# Unable To Search For Dependencies In IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I recall being able to search for dependencies using the console at the bottom of IntelliJ. For example, I was searching for Apache POI.

I can find dependencies on my current laptop's IntelliJ:

However on my other laptop, I am unable to search for anything EXCEPT for existing dependencies that are already in my project. It will simply say: "No dependencies found etc."

I've tried looking for answers and most of them direct me to:

1. Open *pom.xml* -> Right-click on code -> *Generate...* -> *Add dependency...*
2. *File* -> *Invalidate Caches...* -> *Invalidate and Restart*
3. *File* -> *Project Structure...* -> *Modules* -> *Dependencies* -> "+" sign to add jar file -> Search dependency name in console at the bottom

All these still fetches 0 results when I search for keyword like "*poi*".

Comment: Are you trying to find dependencies on Apache POI or add a dependency on Apache POI?

Comment: I suspect it's a network related issue. Please check if configure a proxy or select no proxy from Preferences/Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy help.

Comment: @EthanYin My settings for HTTP Proxy has no proxy, similar to my working laptop.

Comment: @Kirby I am trying to use the package search to look for Apache POI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure if what I have done fixes the issues, but it started working after doing the following steps:

1. Go to *File* -> *Repair IDE*
2. Click on *Rescan project indexes*
3. *Reopen Project*
4. *Actions* -> *Delete Package Search project caches* -> *Delete Package Search global caches*
5. *Reindex project* -> *Invalidate Caches and Restart*
6. Tick everything on the popup menu
7. *Invalidate and Restart*
8. When the popup asks to *Download prebuilt shared indexes*, click on *Always download*

For some reason, my package search has started working again. I am now able to search for dependencies. I have checked that there aren't any network issues. It started working after I have done the above steps.  I hope it can help someone out there with the same problem.

Do note that I am unsure if the above steps may have caused other issues. So far it has posed no other problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're referring to is called Package Search and you can find the docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/package-search.html).
Note that you need internet access to be able to use it, as it connects to the Package Search backend. And also, there are some other [limitations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/package-search-build-system-support-limitations.html) to using this feature.